# A single database value across multiple html input tags

Tags: html, web2py

Is it possible to have a single database value (say, a post/zip code) split across two html input tags (the first 4 digits in the first, and the last 3 in the second).

I am currently using the helper method of displaying the form, but as far as I'm aware, I could use 'raw' html to achieve the same thing (and if this is the case, I would not mind at all changing my view file to have the raw html). So is there a way that I can use raw html, have two input tags for postcode, and somehow combine their values in the controller?

So this is my model file:

```
db.define_table(
        'user_address', 
        Field('street_address', 'string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
        Field('city', 'string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
        Field('country', 'string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
        Field('postcode', 'string', requires=IS_LENGTH(7)),
               )
```

This is my controller:

```
def new():
    form = SQLFORM(db.user_address)
    if form.accepts(request,session):
        response.flash = "form accepted"
    return dict(form = form)
```

And this is my view:

```
<section>
    <h2>Register</h2>
    {{=form.custom.begin}}
    {{=form.custom.widget.street_address}}
    <br>
    {{=form.custom.widget.city}}
    <br>
    {{=form.custom.widget.post_code}}
    <br>
    {{=form.custom.widget.country}}
    <br><br>
    {{=form.custom.submit}}
    {{=form.custom.end}}
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the built-in form processing functionality, breaking up the field into two inputs could get complicated. A simpler approach might be to include two additional fields in the database table and making the combined "postcode" field a computed field:

```
db.define_table('user_address', 
    Field('street_address', 'string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('city', 'string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('country', 'string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('postcode1', label='Postal Code', requires=IS_LENGTH(4)),
    Field('postcode2', requires=IS_LENGTH(3)),
    Field('postcode', compute=lambda r: r.postcode1 + r.postcode2,
          readable=False, writable=False)
```

You would still need to use the custom form code so you can keep the postcode1 and postcode2 inputs inline and suppress the label for postcode2.

The default table definition above will always show the postcode1 and postcode2 fields and hide the postcode field (i.e., in forms and the grid). If you are simply displaying a record (e.g., using the grid feature), you can instead set the `readable` and `writable` attributes of postcode1 and postcode2 to `False` and the postcode attributes to `True`.

One other option would be to define a custom widget for the "postcode" field. The widget should include the two visible input elements you want to display in the form as well as a hidden input element with the name "postcode". You would then need some Javascript (which could be included in the widget code or simply loaded separately) to automatically concatenate the values in the two visible inputs and put the result in the hidden input. The widget code would also have take the existing value in the postcode field and split it into the two visible widgets (this will be necessary for update forms, which display existing values in all of the form inputs).

Comment: Would your answer have been different if I didn't want to use the built-in form processing functionality? Because I really don't mind not using it.

Comment: I strongly suggest using the built-in form processing system when generating create and update forms based on database tables, as it dramatically simplifies things. Even if you don't use `SQLFORM`, you should at least use the `FORM` helper in order to take advantage of its CSRF protection.

Comment: As a more direct answer to your question, no, my answer would not be different, as the two options I suggested above are still probably easier than handling form creation/validation and database inserts manually (particularly if you have to handle record updates as well as inserts). If you go that route, though, the solution should be fairly straightforward (i.e., you'll just have to concatenate the two submitted fields before inserting into the database, and for update forms, you'll have to split the value stored in the database).